# React/tsx open link in new tab using nameless function as the href

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am a bit of a beginner to react and tsx. I want to be able to ctrl click it into a new tab, but in it's current state it doesn't allow that. This seems really easy if you have a constant link to give it, but I've tried everything that I could find and couldn't get it to work with a nameless function.

```
<Button variant="link" onClick={evt => labelClick(entity.id)}>
  { entity.rawDevice.name }
</Button>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share what `labelClick()` does

Comment: You might need to use an <a> element, which you can style like a button (or have a Button as a child of it)

Comment: labelClick() makes makes the link based on an id.

Comment: I've tried to use an a tag but it says href must be keyboard readable or something along those lines so I gave up on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can `Link` component from `react-router-dom`.

```
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';

<Link to='/home' target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">Go to Page</Link>
```

Comment: How can I use my anonymous function in the to?